# How does Number data type work in Oracle 21c?

Tags: oracle, numbers

I created a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table(
    id INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    nome VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)
)    

ALTER TABLE table ADD CONSTRAINT table_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX TABLE_UNIQ_IDX ON TABLE(NOME ASC);

ALTER TABLE table ADD (PERC NUMBER(1, 2) NOT NULL);
```

Then I tried to write 2 records on it:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE(NOME,PERC)VALUES('a',0.8);

INSERT INTO TABLE(NOME,PERC)VALUES('b',0.2);
```

Then I received this error:

> ORA-01438: valor maior que a precisão especificada usado para esta coluna

Translated:

> ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allows for this column

I tried `select cast (0.8 as number(1,1)) from dual;` and it worked but when I tried `select cast (0.8 as number(1,2)) from dual;` I received the same error.

I then tried `select cast (0.81 as number(1,2)) from dual;` and received the same ORA-01438.

I changed my field to `number(1,1)`, no big deal, but how does this "Number" data type work?

- Shouldn't `select cast (0.81 as number(1,2)) from dual;` have worked?
- Why does `select cast (0.81 as number(2,2)) from dual;` work and
- `select cast (0.81 as number(2,3)) from dual;` does not?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3):

If you have `NUMBER(precision, scale)` then `precision` is the number of digits and `scale` is the number of decimal places.

So, `NUMBER(1, 2)` has a single digit and 2 decimal places. The minimum value it can store is `-0.09` and the maximum it can store is `+0.09`.

`NUMBER(2,2)` works as it stores 2 digits in 2 decimal places (from -0.99 to +0.99).

`NUMBER(2,3)` does not work as it stores 2 digits in 3 decimal places (from -0.099 to +0.099).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I thought (completely wrong) that Number(1,2) meant something like 9.99, Number(1.3)=9.999, Number(2.3)=99.999 and so forth. Thank you very much for showing me this.

Answer (score 1):

What you said, is that `perc` column should accept numeric values whose length is `1`, and out of that `1`, you want to keep `2` decimal places. That won't work.

```
SQL> create table test (perc number(1, 2));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values (0.8);
insert into test values (0.8)
                         *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
```

Perhaps you meant to put it vice versa?

```
SQL> alter table test modify perc number(2, 1);

Table altered.

SQL> insert into test values (0.8);

1 row created.

SQL>
```